# Cannot Find Module 'block-stream'

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, cra

I'm trying to make a new react-js site using npx create-react-app
The Error I get is Error: Cannot find module 'block-stream'
I redownloaded node and tried again but still getting the same error
what can I try to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong on anything here, I'm not really a React or Node developer.

However, I'd guess, if it's an addon or additional package, it may not be installed by default.  You might try figuring out if you can install it, somehow.

I don't know if this is what you meant, but I did find [this webpage](https://help.blockstream.com/hc/en-us/articles/900001610743-Install-the-Blockstream-Satellite-node-software#:%7E:text=Blockstream%20Satellite%20Kit%20Setup,-Set%20up%20a&text=Blockstream%20maintains%20a%20customized%20version,normal%20Bitcoin%20Core%20node%20does.) with some details on installing it.

In addition, if you *don't* want to use blockstream, and didn't intentionally include it, and this error is being shown to you for seemingly no reason, I'd suggest looking through your codebase to find any references to that code.

I wish you luck :)

Comment: I might try this.. But I'm also not familiar with this error. Moreover, there are not much to find information about this. But thank you for your idea